# Are there any open source distribution raster merging functions within JTS or GeoTools

Tags: arcobjects, raster, .net, java, merge

I'm looking for something similar to the combine function from the ISelectionSet interface from ArcObject's SDK 10 .NET framework on a more scaled down level. Ergo, I don't plan on using that interface to combine objects that manage rows or features. If I need to I'll do a cast as some type of table like object, but nothing drawing from ArcObjects.

Comment: Not following your train of thought... can you explain a little further? Also JTS is vector-only, it has nothing to do with raster, so not sure why it was mentioned.

Comment: ah okay then I guess I can't use anything from JTS. Simply are there any open source distribution Java tools that I can use to merge raster data sets.

Comment: http://gdal.org/java/

Comment: Not aware of a Java equivalent but the source to [gdal_merge.py](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) might be helpful: http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_merge.py

Comment: Here is someone's Java take on it: http://code.google.com/p/geobricks/source/browse/trunk/geobricks/src/main/java/org/geobricks/gdal/merge/GDALMerge.java?spec=svn40&r=40

Comment: ah ok, thanks @blah238. If you put your second comment as an answer I'll vote it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL)](http://gdal.org/) has [bindings for Java](http://gdal.org/java/).

It also includes a Python script for merging rasters: [gdal_merge.py](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) (source code [here](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_merge.py))

Lastly [here](http://code.google.com/p/geobricks/source/browse/trunk/geobricks/src/main/java/org/geobricks/gdal/merge/GDALMerge.java?spec=svn40&r=40) is someone's take on a Java version of the gdal_merge tool.